# Set Use Storyboard Id Programmatically iOS

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to set the property of a ViewController: `Use Storyboard Id`. You can set it in the storyboard easily:

[image: Storyboard]

(Use Storyboard ID is checked)

How can I do this programmatically using Swift? Thanks!

Comment: The checkbox isn't a property of the view controller, it is just a bit of data inside the storyboard file that tells IB to set the restoration identifier to the same value as the storyboard ID. What exactly are you trying to do?  A storyboard file is just an xml document so I guess you could write some code to modify the file by reading it in and writing it back out with the attribute changed but you can't do this at runtime in an app

Comment: @Paulw11 I was trying to make all of my view controllers use storyboard ids. I have them as a subclass of a separate ViewController, and it would be very easy if I could do it programmatically.

Comment: As I said, this checkbox is just an attribute in the storyboard file.  You can right-click the storyboard in Xcode and select "open as source" and then add the `useStoryboardIdentifierAsRestorationIdentifier="YES"` attribute to the `viewController` elements - Something like `<viewController storyboardIdentifier="VC1" useStoryboardIdentifierAsRestorationIdentifier="YES" id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="LocationTest" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">`

Comment: But again, this would be for a specific `viewController`. How could I make it for all `viewController`s? Thanks

Comment: You have to edit the file for all view controllers; either using the dialog in IB or by editing the XML, perhaps using a find/replace.  There is no way to set it 'automatically'

Answer (score 0):

To set the storyboard ID programmatically in Swift, you can use the storyboardIdentifier property of the UIViewController class. Here's how you can do it:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewControllerIdentifier") as! YourViewControllerClass 
viewController.storyboardIdentifier = "YourNewStoryboardIdentifier
```

In the code above, you first instantiate the view controller from the storyboard using the instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:) method, passing in the existing identifier you want to modify. Then, you access the storyboardIdentifier property of the view controller and assign it the new identifier value you want to set.

Make sure to replace "Main" with the actual name of your storyboard file, "YourViewControllerIdentifier" with the identifier of the view controller you want to modify, and "YourNewStoryboardIdentifier" with the new identifier value you want to set.

Note that setting the storyboard ID programmatically does not update the storyboard file itself. It only sets the identifier value during runtime.